# Determine how many socks have to be drawn

Tags: combinatorics

So my question is :

> Consider there are $A$ red socks, $B$ green socks and $C$ Yellow socks in a dark room. And we want to find $N$ pairs of matching colored socks from the dark room.
>   Given all $A$, $B$ and $C$ are even and $N \leq  (A+B+C)/2$, how many socks need to be drawn from the dark room in the worst case, to have exactly $N$ pairs?

I understand that in order to be sure that we draw at least one matching pair, the answer is trivially $N+1$ ([Number of socks to guarantee getting a matching pair.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325149/number-of-socks-to-guarantee-getting-a-matching-pair/325155#325155) ) I am facing difficulty when the value of $N$ is greater than 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you draw $2k$ or $2k+1$ socks if the same color, you get $k$ pairs, so you "lose" a sock when a color is chosen an odd number of times. However, by taking an even number of socks, at most two colors may be odd-numbered.

Therefore, the answer is $2N+2$.

(This is true if $2N+1 \le A+B+C -3$ because otherwise you cannot lose three socks.)

Comment: You are right, I will add the appropriate condition.